# How to create alias in Ebean query

Tags: java, postgresql, ebean

```
String sql = "select * from ( " +
            "select u.id as userId, earth_distance(ll_to_earth(" + latitude + ", " + longitude + "), ll_to_earth(c.latitude, c.longitude)) as distance " +
            "from user u " +
            "join city c on u.city_id = c.id " +
            ") s " +
            "where distance <= 100000 " +
            "order by distance";

SqlQuery query = Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql);
```

How can I create equivalent using Ebean expressionList?
I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
ExpressionList<User> expressionList = Ebean.find(User.class)
            .select("*, earth_distance(ll_to_earth(" + latitude + ", " + longitude + "), ll_to_earth(city.latitude, city.longitude)) as distance")
            .where()
            .lt("distance", maxDistance);
expressionList.orderBy("distance");
```

but distance alias is not created.